# Finding this probability, I need some explanation.

Tags: probability, statistics

If green and yellow seeds per plants are crossed and $15$ seeds are obtained calculate the probability of getting $(0,1,2,....15)$ green seeds. Green is a  dominant and hybrid gene, yellow is a recessive gene.
What will be sample space, event and the probability for green to be 0, 1 and so on?

Comment: Can you fix your spelling errors?? I'm having trouble understanding this question

Comment: Is the green seed parent heterozygous or homozygous?

Comment: If green is Heterozygous then? What will be the probability of getting 0 greens, 1 green and so on upto 15?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use the chart(2x2) that is usually taught in 7th grade that is used to find the probability? If not here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square
Then, use the Counting Principle to find all the probabilities for all of the independent events. Hope this helped!